# Vim: Just discovered `ci"` - can I append?

Tags: vim, text-editors

I've recently found out the command `ci"` to replace `"text inside quotes"`. I want to instead *append* the text in the quotes (to get, say, `"text inside quotes with some more"`), without deleting the existing text. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use <kbd>f</kbd><kbd>"</kbd> or  <kbd>t</kbd><kbd>"</kbd> to jump to the next quotation mark, where you can start appending or inserting text.

Comment: Of course! Thank you, don't know what I was thinking.